# Understanding cmp instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, comparison

I'm very new to assembly and now I'm trying to understand how `cmp` works. Here is what's written in [***wiki***](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Comparison_Instructions):

```
cmp arg2, arg1
```

> Performs a comparison operation between arg1 and arg2. The comparison
> is performed by a (signed) subtraction of arg2 from arg1, the results
> of which can be called Temp. **Temp is then discarded**.

What does it mean *"Temp is then discarded"*? Where is it stored? How can I access this result of the comparison? Can someone explain it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate *ax? Cos AFAIK it's often used with `je`. But je needs to know if condition was true or false.

Comment: Note that you're referring to *wikibooks*, which is a particular collection of *wikis*. A *wiki* is just a type of website that users can edit. And as such, wikibooks definitely isn't the prime ressource for x86 assembly definitions (this one is a good example why it's sometimes better to rely on expert documentation than user-generated documentation). Use google to find another source, and interpret that!

Comment: `je` doesn't need to know if condition was true or false, `je` is alias of `jz`, and `jz` is "jump if zero flag is set". So whatever last instruction did modify the ZF, that one will foretold whether next `je` will take a jump (ZF=1) or not (ZF=0). One of the funny consequences of new asm programmers not getting it, is writing code like `sub ax,1` `cmp ax,0` `jne myLoop` ... that `cmp` is not needed there, as previous `sub` will already set ZF in a sufficient way for that `jne` work (but more logical would be to use `jnz myLoop` alias, i.e. reads as "jump not zero loop" - almost English.

Comment: "The comparison is performed by a (signed) subtraction" -- Subtraction with 2's complement numbers isn't either signed or unsigned, both are the exact same operation. `jz`/`je` and `jnz`/`jne` don't care about whether a comparison was signed or unsigned, either. However, other x86 comparison conditional branches do need to be specified as signed or unsigned. Signed ones are called "jump if (not) less/less-or-equal/greater/greater-or-equal", giving the instructions `jl`, `jg`, etc. Unsigned comparison conditionals are called "jump if (not) below/above/etc", `jb`, `ja`, etc.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`cmp arg2, arg1` performs the same operation as `sub arg2, arg1` *except* that none of the operands are modified. The difference is not stored *anywhere*.

However, the flags register *is* updated and can be used in a conditional jump, like jump-if-equal (`JE`), most often as the next instruction after the `cmp`.

The advantage over other instructions is that you can compare two values without destroying any of them. If you did `sub arg2, arg1` and they happen to be equal, one of them would be zero afterwards. With `cmp` they are both still there.

Comment: Are the args the same in Intel and ATT?

Answer (score 41):

the results of CMP is changing the values of ZF and CF, this is some examples to understand very much CMP instruction.

Example 1: if AX < BX

```
MOV AX,5
MOV BX,8
CMP AX,BX
```

Result : ZF and CF set to ==> "ZF = 0"  and "CF = 1"

---

---

Example 2 : if AX > BX

```
MOV AX,8
MOV BX,5
CMP AX,BX
```

Result : ZF and CF set to ==> "ZF = 0"  and "CF = 0"

---

---

Example 3 : if AX = BX

```
MOV AX,5
MOV BX,AX
CMP AX,BX
```

Result : ZF and CF set to ==> "ZF = 1"  and "CF = 0"

---

---

i hope you understand the results of CMP is changing the value of ZF and CF
ZF = Zero Flag
CF = Carry Flag

Answer (score 16):

We use `cmp arg2, arg1` when we care about whether arg1 and arg 2 are equal. The processor determines this by subtracting arg2 from arg1, then looking at the result. If the result is zero (that is, arg1 = arg2), then the processor sets the zero flag (by "sets the flag", we mean it sets it to 1). Conversely, if the result isn't zero (that is, arg1 != arg2), then the processor clears the zero flag (i.e, sets it to 0). The result itself is discarded, because we don't care what it is, only whether it's zero or not, which we now know based on whether the zero flag is set. We can then use instructions like `JE`, `JNE`, `JZ` and `JNZ` that examine the zero flag and jump (or not) based on its value. In the case of `JE` (jump if equal), the jump will happen if the zero flag is set, which (as we learned above) it will be if the arguments in the `cmp` were equal.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's very late to post an answer on this question. But I can give you a better illustration on how this CMP instruction works.

When you Compare two arguments using `CMP  arg1,  arg2`

CMP instruction sets status flags according to the comparisons between the arguments.
See : [wikipedia's FLAGS page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register)

The importance of CMP applies mostly in conditional code execution (Jump - See : [assembly_conditions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_conditions.htm)). When the processor executes a conditional-jump [`jcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc) instruction, it checks the status flags register and jumps to the target label if it meets the conditions, otherwise falls through to the next instruction.